# How necessary is symbolication for ParseCrashReporter

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

Is it a big deal if I leave this out? Will it be confusing to me when reading the crash logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the Parse crash reporter, but if it's anything like Crashlytics, then the stack traces will only give a clue as to what is causing the crash if you don't upload the symbols during your build.  If the crash reporter has your symbols then the stack traces will show the line causing the issue.  This will save you shed-loads of time.

Crashlytics provide a program to run during the build to automate this upload process, so it's no hassle to do it at all; you simply create an *External Build System* Xcode target and make the app dependent upon that target.

I don't know what Parse do to help you do this.